# Where are the default desktop pictures in Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, pictures, slideshow

In Windows 10 I found the Windows desktop background under `C:\Users\[your user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\BackgroundSlideshow\`.

The default lock screen pictures can be found here: `C:\Users\[your user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\LockScreenSlideshow\`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question. You're asking where the default desktop backgrounds are but, in the question's body you list the file paths of the backgrounds.

Comment: Tested on my Windows 10. No such folders exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking where lies the default wallpapers, it's here

```
C:\windows\web\wallpaper
```